# PouchDB find() returns empty array after delete 1 of 6 objects from db

Tags: pouchdb

Here is my db.find():

```
db.createIndex({
  index: {
    fields: ['username', 'date'],
    name: 'usernameDateIndex',
    ddoc: "usernameDateIndex"
  }
}).then(() => {
  db.find({
    selector: {
      username: 'org.couchdb.user:' + name
    },
    sort: [{username: 'desc'}, {date:'desc'}],
    use_index: 'usernameDateIndex'
  }).then(result => {
    // Works fine. I get what is expected
  }).catch(error => {
  });
}).catch(error => {
});
```

This works fine and returns an array with six docs. I then delete one doc like this:

```
doc._deleted = true;
db.put(
  doc
).then(response => {
  // db.allDocs() returns 5 docs this is correct
  // db.find() returns an empty array
}).catch(error => {
});
```

After the delete, db.AllDocs() works correctly but the same db.createIndex and db.find() listed above returns and empty array. I have also tried db.find() after the delete without the db.createIndex() and I still get an empty array and I get no errors.

Am I missing a step here? Do I need to do some sort of commit after the delete? Do I need to delete the index and create it again? Do I need to force replication with my CouchDB remote server? Not sure what is going on.

One last thing, this is a React Native app that is using pouchdb-react-native and pouchdb-find packages. It's backing storage is AsyncStorage.

Comment: This issue happens if i change any existing field in the doc I put(). It is not just related to setting _deleted = true. I now believe this is by design and I just don't have an option needed to return all of my valid docs.

Comment: As [explained here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html "Mango queries"), you can try the `explain` API of PouchDB to debug: `db.explain({
  selector: {
    //...
  }
})
.then(explained => {
  // detailed explained info can be viewed
});`

Comment: I have used explain, and both the find() that works and the one that doesn't are explained exactly the same and are using the correct indexes and correct selectors and sorts.

Answer (score -1):

Take a loot at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47578641/3405291), according to item 2 of the answer:

> 2. At query time, an index can only be used if all it's indexed fields
>      are required to exist according to the selector. For example, **if your
>      index contains fields A and B but you only query for A, we can't use
>      the index** because it won't include documents that contain A but not B.

Maybe that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I changed the selector to include both fields. It still does not work. Seems to happen after I try to mark _deleted = true on one doc.

Comment: The consequences of the circumstances in this answer would be a slower query (by not using the index), not a failed/empty result set.