# React native PouchDB get hangs

Tags: ios, react-native, ecmascript-6, promise, pouchdb

I have a promise chain where I get the content from local DB, update it with the latest fetched from API. This cycle is run whenever user eg opens a content. It works well. Except when the user is opening the app through a deep link. Eg, I go to the company website, I have the deep link option in the safari, I open it. It successfully fetches the content opened from the website, goes into the promise lifecycle where it tries to load and update the content but it just hangs. All input data is correct and it doesn't make sense why it hangs at all.

PouchDB is using adapter `pouchdb-adapter-react-native-sqlite` with `react-native-sqlite-2`

```
createDBIndex()
          .then(() => {
              console.groupCollapsed('Updating existing content');
              console.log(toUpdateArray);
              console.log('Fetching articles and indexes');

              return Promise.all(toUpdateArray.map(({ _id }) => DB.articles.get(_id)));
          })
          .then(dbArticles => {
              console.log('Resolving finders-keepers');
              console.log(dbArticles);
              const updatedContent = dbArticles.map(dbItem => {
                  const toUpdate = toUpdateArray.find(item => item._id === dbItem._id);
                  return {
                      ...dbItem,
                      ...toUpdate,
                      expire: moment().add(1, 'd').format()
                  };
              });
              return DB.articles.bulkDocs(updatedContent).then(() => updatedContent);
          })
          .then(updatedDBArray => {
              console.log('update result', updatedDBArray);
              console.groupEnd();
              return updatedDBArray;
          })
```

The last `console.log` it gives is `Fetching articles and indexes` and the whole app freeze. tried to print the `PouchDB` get function result or error but nothing. It doesn't get resolved or rejected.

Comment: Did you found the reason for this behavior. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I can share is that recently people have problems using PouchDB in a React Native environment which is using AsynchStorage as its backing storage. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49785164/3405291) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49719678/3405291) and also [this issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7219).

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using sqlite plugin. But will have a look on those links maybe will found something helpful, thanks!